Movie where man warns people of rising water from a dam
A man has a job going around to warn people that the rising waters of a recently completed dam will inundate their homes and they need to move out. Some people seem to not understand what this means. In the process he meets some very odd people and some interesting creatures. 

The man is played by a mainstream American actor, if I remember correctly. 
I remember a desert landscape.
Some might consider this a comedy, probably a dark comedy.    
It is probably an independent film. 
It was probably filmed in the 70s-90s, sorry I can't be more specific. 
It was in color.
I saw it on TV but it was not a "made for TV" movie.


I have a feeling it may be "Killer Flood". When did you watch it?

Not Killer Flood. That is a TV movie made in 2003 and is no way a comedy, even a dark one. Plus the movie I describe is not about a flood because of a breaking dam but about homes being flooded behind a dam as the river water is backed up and rising. The man is not running around because of imminent danger, He's just letting the people who haven't left yet know they need to make plans to move. I'm pretty sure I watched it sometime in the 80s or 90s.

This almost sounds like a documentary...

It is most certainly not a documentary. When I say he meets creatures, I do not mean animals. I mean very unusual entities, So there is an element of fantasy in the show. It is a very odd movie. When I think of the main character, my brain sees Robert Duval, but there is nothing like this in his body of work. But the main character is played by someone mainstream like Duvall. I remember being surprised that this actor was in such an odd movie.

I have discovered the name of the movie.  Northfork. It was released in 2003, so I missed on the date,  Netflix description: Thanks to a newly constructed dam, days are numbered in the town of Northfork, Mont., where six men are charged with clearing the area of its last hangers-on: a couple, a man who owns an ark and a nearly comatose orphan.<br.> The mainstream actor who left an impression as Robert Duvall? James Woods. Also in the film are Nick Nolte, Peter Coyote and Daryl Hannah.  One posting on IMDB suggested that fans of David Lynch would enjoy this film.

I was able to find the film because of ideas for searching that I got on this site.  Thanks!

@Dash: Please post this as an answer, and click the check mark to mark it "accepted".  Otherwise this question will remain on the "unanswered" list forever.

The name of the movie is Northfork. It was released in 2003, so I missed on the date, Netflix description: Thanks to a newly constructed dam, days are numbered in the town of Northfork, Mont., where six men are charged with clearing the area of its last hangers-on: a couple, a man who owns an ark and a nearly comatose orphan. The mainstream actor who left an impression as Robert Duvall? James Woods. Also in the film are Nick Nolte, Peter Coyote and Daryl Hannah. One posting on IMDB suggested that fans of David Lynch would enjoy this film.
I found the film by searching Netflix with the keyword "flood" and it was one of the choices that came up several screens in.

Don't forget to accept this answer if it is the correct solution to your problem.
